# Sorting listview with values from dropdown asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, listview, drop-down-menu

I have a listview which is populated from database and is manually binded in codebehind with BindGrid(). This works fine and gets all the right data.

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, constr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        listView.DataSource = dt;
        listView.DataBind();
```

I have two dropdowns. One contains sorting through, ALL, Country, Price Low - High, Price High To Low.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSorting" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLSorting_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="All"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Country" Value="Country"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Price - Lowest to Highest" Value="PriceL"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Price - Highest to Lowest" Value="PriceH"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When Country is selected it should populate the second dropdown called ddlCountries with SELECT Distinct Countries otherwise it is disabled.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountries" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled = "false" >
    <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Country--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Problems I am having:

1. When I select anything from dropdown the listview doesn't rebind/refresh with the new sorted data? I have tried putting `BindGrid()`; in each of the if statement but that didn't work!
2. Not sure of how to bind the countries when Country is selected to the second dropdown?

`

```
protected void ddlSorting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(con);
    string query = string.Empty;
    if (DDLSorting.SelectedValue == "All")
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM Wines";
    }
    else if (DDLSorting.SelectedValue == "Country")
    {
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Wines";
        DDLCountries.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM Wines ORDER BY price {0}";

        if (DDLSorting.SelectedValue == "PriceL")
        {
            query = string.Format(query, "ASC");
        }
        else if(DDLSorting.SelectedValue == "PriceH")
        {
            query = string.Format(query, "DESC");
        }
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
    Con.Open();
    BindGrid();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to close the `SqlConnection (Con)`...

Comment: What does BindGrid() do? It seems to me your are not binding any data to ddlCountries

Comment: BindGrid() binds the data to listview and I call it in pageload so when the page is loaded it displays the list @PaoloCosta

Comment: You're right I haven't binded any data to ddlCountries yet. My main concern right now is that when I select price ASC or DESC it doesn't sort the data... When click it from dropdown it doesn't display any errors and doesn't rebind the data @PaoloCosta

Comment: Please help guys have been stuck on this for a week now and can't figure it out!!

Comment: As I said in the answer that your goal is not clear. What's the meaning of sorting by all? Usually a sort dropdownlist contains some fields you want to sort by (price, date, name etc....). It seems to me you are confusing sorting with filtering

Comment: Yes I am sorting by price, country. ASC Desc. The ALL is meant to go back to the original and display all the wines? @PaoloCosta

Comment: When you sort by something you are not changing the number of displayed items but only the order in which they are displayed. So you understand it doesn't make much sense to say "when I choose All it displays all the wines" because it always displays all the wines! You have to understand this otherwise you cannot go on.

Comment: @PaoloCosta Yes, but what I meant by ALL is to go back to the original state which is ordered by ID of the wines.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well @PaoloCosta

Comment: Ok, don't use All, that doesn't make sense, Put "Default" instead. But I still need to understand your goal. Please tell me in plain text what you want to achieve. Don't use technical language, just describe the use case.

Comment: Don't worry, as soon as I have time I'm glad to help you

Comment: Ok basically, user views all the wines by default, if they want to sort them they are able to do so by using the dropdown. In the dropdown it has the price, alcohol precentage, If they select Price Low to High the order of the wines should be changed accordingly in the listview with the price being from Low to High and vise versa (i.e. high to low). If they select precentage, it should be same as price so from low to high, high to low. I also added Countries in there because I thought it'd be easier to just have them all in one dropdown instead of having multiples... @PaoloCosta

Comment: Ok, now it's clear: You need the countries in another dropdown, I'll provide you a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

After the discussion, this is the proposed solution. I did some assumptions and the code is not optimal at all, but I hope it's easy to understand. I'm not 100%.  sure it works as I cannot test it (and I'm not also sure this code is SQL injection safe! :-))

ASPX  Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSorting"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSorting_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="default">Default</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Country">Country</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Price ASC">Price ASC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Price DESC">Price DESC</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="Country" DataTextField="Country" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="all">All</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:ListView ID="lstResult" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <!-- template code omitted -->

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

And the code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCountries();
            LoadWines();
        }
    }

    private void LoadCountries()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Wines", conn);
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlCountries.DataSource = reader;
        ddlCountries.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void LoadWines()
    {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Wines";
        if (ddlCountries.SelectedValue != "all")
        {
            query = query + " WHERE Country =  '" + ddlCountries.SelectedValue + "'";
        }
        if (ddlSorting.SelectedValue != "default")
        {
            query = query + " ORDER BY " + ddlSorting.SelectedValue;
        }

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        lstResult.DataSource = reader;
        lstResult.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void ddlSorting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadWines();
    }

    protected void ddlCountries_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadWines();
    }
```

You have to load the countries only once, and use the selected value to filter the wines of a specific country if requested by the user. Everytime the user changes the selection the wines are reloaded.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to write this up I appreciate it greatly! I have added it to my code but I have got an error `Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'all'.` and it highlights `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` in LoadWines

Comment: Is it a SqlException?

Comment: Yes, also I don't know if this will affect the way the code is coded but my ListView is also using DataPager (for paging the wines)

Comment: Well, sorry but this you have to figure out by yourself, I can't do the whole homework for you.

Comment: Sorry it's not homework, i'm trying to improve my asp.net c# skills so i give my self tasks to do. receiving this error ListView with id 'listView' must have a data source that either implements ICollection or can perform data source paging if AllowPaging is true. :(

Comment: I suggest to deeply understand how the code works. Debug it. In case there is another exception try to fix it by yourself, otherwise the excercise is completely unuseful.

Comment: Try to find a solution by yourself please. I don't have any more time now. First of all disable paging and make it work, then you can try to add paging, but only after it works fine without it.

Comment: I have changed it SqlDataApater and it has loaded and displayed the results however it's giving me sql exception near all again

Comment: I have also tried your suggest way and disabled paging and used it with your code but it giving me sqlexception near "all" again :(

Comment: But it fills the second dropdown with the countries

Comment: Another mistake, code updated. Now it works fine on my machine, I also created a database.

Comment: query = query + " ORDER BY " + ddlCountries.SelectedValue instead of query = query + " ORDER BY " + ddlSorting.SelectedValue